# Is there a way to extract each matching result of a sed script to a file each?

Tags: text-processing

I have a file structured like the one below, only with more sections:

```
SCN DD1251       At Glasgow Road - Kilbowie Road                                
Modified                   By ________                                          
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
        DD1271      C           DD1271    R                                     
        DD1351      D           DD1351    B                                     
                    E                                                           
                                                                                
SCN DD1271       At Glasgow Road - Hume Street                                  
Modified 13-OCT-15 15:06   By BDAVIDSON                                         
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
        DD1301      T           DD1301    A                                     
        DD1251      R           DD1251    C                                     
                                                                                
SCN DD1301       At Glasgow Road - Argyll Road - Cart Street                    
Modified 27-JUN-16 11:45   By BDAVIDSON                                         
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
        DD1271      A           DD1271    T                                     
                    B                                                           
                    C                                                           
                    D                                                           
                                                                                
SCN DD1351       At Kilbowie Road - Chalmers Street                             
Modified  9-FEB-21 08:57   By BDAVIDSON                                         
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
                    A           DD1251    D                                     
        DD1251      B                                                           
                    C                                                           
                                                                                
SCN DD1451       At Kilbowie Road - Montrose Street                             
Modified  9-FEB-21 08:58   By BDAVIDSON                                         
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WC  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
                    A                                                           
                    B                                                           
                    C                                                           
                                                                                
SCN DD1601       At Kilbowie Road - Thomson Street 3G                           
Modified  9-FEB-21 08:59   By BDAVIDSON                                         
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WV  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
                    A                                                           
                    B                                                           
                    C                                                           
                    D                                                           
                                                                                
SCN DD1621       At Argyll Road - Stanford Street 3G                            
Modified  9-FEB-21 08:59   By BDAVIDSON                                         
Type CR                                                                         
Region  AS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
                    B                                                           
                    C                                                           
                    D
```

Currently, I am using the following bash script containing a sed function to pull out each section of data from one SCN to the line of no characters between entires:

```
sed -n '/^SCN/,/^\s*$/p' LOG.TXT > Junction-Links.txt
```

This produces the following output:

```
SCN DD1251       At Glasgow Road - Kilbowie Road                                
Modified                   By ________                                          
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
        DD1271      C           DD1271    R                                     
        DD1351      D           DD1351    B                                     
                    E                                                           
                                                                                
SCN DD1271       At Glasgow Road - Hume Street                                  
Modified 13-OCT-15 15:06   By BDAVIDSON                                         
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
        DD1301      T           DD1301    A                                     
        DD1251      R           DD1251    C
```

My question is, is it possible to save each matching pattern to a separate file (i.e a file for SCN DD1251, a file for SCN DD1271 etc.) rather than saving them all into one combined file?

Ideally the output would be like so:

- SCN DD1251.txt
- SCN DD1271.txt
- SCN DD1301.txt
- SCN DD1351.txt

With SCN DD1251.txt simply containing the following:

```
SCN DD1251       At Glasgow Road - Kilbowie Road                                
Modified                   By ________                                          
Type CR                                                                         
Region  WS  Subregion                                                           
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER              
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK               
        DD1271      C           DD1271    R                                     
        DD1351      D           DD1351    B                                     
                    E
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '/^SCN/{close(out); out=$1" "$2".txt"} {print > out}' file
```

```
$ head SCN*
==> SCN DD1251.txt <==
SCN DD1251       At Glasgow Road - Kilbowie Road
Modified                   By ________
Type CR
Region  WS  Subregion
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK
        DD1271      C           DD1271    R
        DD1351      D           DD1351    B
                    E


==> SCN DD1271.txt <==
SCN DD1271       At Glasgow Road - Hume Street
Modified 13-OCT-15 15:06   By BDAVIDSON
Type CR
Region  WS  Subregion
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK
        DD1301      T           DD1301    A
        DD1251      R           DD1251    C


==> SCN DD1301.txt <==
SCN DD1301       At Glasgow Road - Argyll Road - Cart Street
Modified 27-JUN-16 11:45   By BDAVIDSON
Type CR
Region  WS  Subregion
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK
        DD1271      A           DD1271    T
                    B
                    C
                    D

==> SCN DD1351.txt <==
SCN DD1351       At Kilbowie Road - Chalmers Street
Modified  9-FEB-21 08:57   By BDAVIDSON
Type CR
Region  WS  Subregion
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK
                    A           DD1251    D
        DD1251      B
                    C


==> SCN DD1451.txt <==
SCN DD1451       At Kilbowie Road - Montrose Street
Modified  9-FEB-21 08:58   By BDAVIDSON
Type CR
Region  WC  Subregion
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK
                    A
                    B
                    C


==> SCN DD1601.txt <==
SCN DD1601       At Kilbowie Road - Thomson Street 3G
Modified  9-FEB-21 08:59   By BDAVIDSON
Type CR
Region  WV  Subregion
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK
                    A
                    B
                    C
                    D

==> SCN DD1621.txt <==
SCN DD1621       At Argyll Road - Stanford Street 3G
Modified  9-FEB-21 08:59   By BDAVIDSON
Type CR
Region  AS  Subregion
            UPSTREAM               DOWNSTREAM               FILTER
          NODE     LINK          NODE    LINK                LINK
                    B
                    C
                    D
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use csplit:

```
csplit -z -f 'SCN DD' Junction-Links.txt '/^\s*$/' '{*}'
```

Although this will make files named 'SCN DD00', 'SCN DD01', 'SCN DD02' etc. If
you have more than 100 files, you can add `-n 3` to use a three digit padding
in the output files.